# GetFormat never gets an IFormatProvider type

Tags: c#, format, iformatprovider

In a WinGrid (Infragistics, if you must know) I got a column containing `int`s. The value is a number of seconds, from which you can calculate a time. I created an IFormatProvider/ICustomFormatter that does just that. During my grid initialization, I set the Format and FormatInfo parameters.

However, when GetFormat is called on my custom type formatter, the type parameter is always a NumberFormatInfo, and never an ICustomFormatter. Why?

Here is my class, in case it helps :

```
public class SecToTime : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
        {
            return this;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        if (arg is int)
        {
            int seconds = (int)arg;
            int hours = (int)Math.Truncate((double)seconds / 3600);
            int minutes = (int)Math.Truncate((double)(seconds / 60) % 60);
            seconds = seconds % 60;
            return string.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss}", new DateTime(0, 0, 0, hours, minutes, seconds));
        }
        else
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the (great) Mike Salzman from Infragistics Team:

> The FormatInfo will not be called
>   unless the Format property is also
>   set. That's the only reason I can
>   think of why it would not be called.

Source: [this Infragistics forum's post](http://community.infragistics.com/forums/p/18935/107515.aspx#107515)

To test it, try to set the column `Format` property to something... :)

Comment: It's set to something. I tried different things, but it doesn't seem to change the type parameter that GetFormat receives.

Comment: Strange... is your underlying datasource a DataTable? If it's the case, is the Type of the corresponding dataTable column set to `int` ?

Comment: The underlying datasource is a bindingsource, and the bindingsource's datasource is the datatable. My column.DataType is an Int32.

Comment: Mmh, I just did this test --> [(link)](http://pastebin.com/yL8BZ8y6) and it works fine... do you notice something really different from your code ?

Comment: Wow, I just can't see what's different :-S  The only thing I see is that you subscribe the grid to InitializeLayout in the form's constructor, but I did it via the designer. I changed my .Format to "####" (I tried different things) and it's still the same problem. I'll delete/recreate my grid to see if something obscured happened, and I'll keep you posted. Thanks A LOT for your help sir!

Comment: @Tipx: well, so I have no idea... you could try to ask in the infragistics forum. If you can reproduce the problem in a small project you can also post it and they will look at it...

Comment: @Tipx: otherwise, you can also download infragistics source code and `.pdb` files and try to debug it yourself :)

Comment: I tried creating a new grid and all, and it kept doing the same thing. I don't know if the problem is with my version of infragistics or not, but I just asked the question in infragistics' forum.

Comment: Mike answered me, and it looks like it's a bug that was corrected in a newer release! Here's the link to infragistic's post : http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/p/53107/275535.aspx

Comment: @Tipx: oh, you were using infragistics 7... I was trying on infragistics 10, so this explains all :D